# Sample size for medical device which provides repeated measurements

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size, continuous-data, measurement

I have a medical device which provides continuous measurements of a substance in the body (X) over time.

There is currently an established reference standard (Y) which measures the same substance but in a different body compartment - there is a relationship between levels of X and Y but the precise relationships over time are not defined.

Given that repeated measurements (in the same individual) are obtained and that there is no gold standard, could someone point me towards the considerations in designing a study to evaluate the performance of the medical device?

I have read that Bland-Altman methods for repeated sampling might be useful but am unclear if this applies as X and Y are essentially different measurements to a degree. Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of measuring X? Let's say we knew the device measured X perfectly (and we could also measure Y perfectly). What would be the relation between them? Is the idea that it's the same thing as measuring Y (i.e. you can just measure one instead of the other and physicians can interpret the results as before?)? Or is the idea that one can convert X to Y (e.g. always 10% higher? Or do they both measure the same underlying thing Z? Or is Y established as surrogate for something & the idea is that X will be a better surrogate? Or do they have to be interpreted completely differently?

Comment: Thanks! X is much more easier to measure than Y and much less invasive. X and Y both measure the same thing but in different body compartments so even though there is a realtionship, it's unclear how consistent it is..